# How to paste two matlab graphs together?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have two Matlab graphs. The first graph is a histogram with the range from 0 to 1 only. Another graph is a histogram with the range from 100 to 120. If I plot the two histograms on the same graph simultaneously, we can obtain a plot such that the first histogram is too narrow which is difficult to view. So I would like to generate the first graph and the second graph separately and paste them together. So the final graph would paste two graphs together. My idea is in a new graph with axis range from 0 to 5, I plot the first histogram with the range from 0 to 1 and plot the second histogram with the range from 3 to 5, then relabel the x-tick to the desired values. Are there any ways to do it?

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to better follow your problem

Answer (score 0):

Following your idea, rescale your data [100,120] -> [3,5], and relabel the x-axis.

```
A = rand(100,1);
B = 100 + 20*rand(100,1);

figure
hist(A, 5) %adjust number of bins to better match width of other hist
hold on
Bb = (B-100)/20*2 + 3;
hist(Bb)
set(gca, 'xtick', 0:5)
set(gca, 'xticklabel', {'0', '1', '', '100', '110', '120'})
```

ps. Why don't you use `subplot`?